# Possible to create an overflow table which will contain MySQL table data

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, overflow

I have a web page which displays a table listing 50 products with product information (ID, price, stock and colour) from a mysql table.

As I am designing this webpage for a specific resolution and system I would like to display the information in two tables side by side, rather than using one table with a overflow scrollbar.

Currently I have done this by using two tables posited next to each other and then inserting half of the products into each table with the use of 'between' function to select each half by the product ID:

Table 1:

```
"SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID between '01' AND '25'"
```

and Table 2:

```
"SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID between '26' AND '50'"
```

This works and does what I initially wanted but as I would also like to add 'sort by' buttons this option won't work. For example if I wanted to sort the tables by colour the two tables will only sort their specified half of the data.

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a separate overflow table that will just continue to list the information in order in both tables as if it was just one table?

Allowing me to use:

```
"SELECT * FROM products"
```

with the relevant 'sort' options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point you to a post I made about splitting an array into multiple columns of data similar to how [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/array_chunk) works but "vertically", this means you can apply your sorting to a single SQL query and then split your array output afterwards and loop through your "tables of data"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8735136/61795

```
function array_chunk_vertical($array,$cols = 3, $pad = array(null))
{
  if (is_array($array) == true and empty($array) != true)
  {
    // total items in the array
    $count = count($array);
    // count the number of vertical rows
    $rows = ceil($count/$cols);
    // group the array into colums
    $array = array_chunk($array,$rows);
    // if the array is less that the number of cols required
    // pad it to ensure length remains constant
    if (count($array) < $cols)
    {
      $array = array_pad($array,$cols,$pad);
    }
    // pad the array with a null character as required
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
      $array[$key] = array_pad($value,$rows,null);
    }
    // now inverse the rows with the cols
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
      foreach($value as $sub_key => $sub_value)
      {
        $output[$sub_key][$key] = $sub_value;
      }
    }
    // spit it out
    return $output;
  }
  else
  {
    // oops
    return $array;
  }
}
```