# PHP how can I display cards in 2 columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a method which finds all cards using a SQL statement to find all results. It looks as follows:

```
<?php $cards = find_all_cards();
foreach {$cards as $card} echo "card->username";
?>
```

I can use it to list all cards one after another, but I can't do that if I have 2 columns, because I need to create a new row. Ideally, I'd populate 1st column with half of results, and 2nd with other half.

Also I'd like to be able to sort my results using a filter, is it done via php? So for example sort by ascending username (I have many more fields that I could sort by)

FUNCTIONS:

```
  public static function find_all() {
    return static::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ".static::$table_name);
  }


public static function find_by_sql($sql=""){

     global $database;
     $result_set = $database->query($sql);
     $object_array = array();
     while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) {
       $object_array[]=static::instantiate($row);
     }
     return $object_array;
   }


   private static function instantiate($record){
   $class_name = get_called_class();
   $object = new $class_name;

   foreach($record as $attribute=>$value) {
    if($object->has_attribute($attribute)) {
      $object->$attribute = $value;
    }

   }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve. It might be easier to solve it on the front end. Like Angular or just plain Css, if the sorting is not essential.

Comment: I don’t see any SQL statement you your sample. It would be really helpful if you could share ahat `find_all_cards` is doing.

Comment: By sorting, do you mean dynamically after the event, or when the data is fetched? I’m going to try to guess where you’re headed, but (a) if you want to sort the results, you should probably do that in the SQL statement, and (b) if you want simply to generate a 2-column layout, then CSS is your friend.

Comment: I want these cards http://playground.eca.ed.ac.uk/~s1670810/leverage_edinburgh/public/search.php to be in 2 rows. And add a filter to sort by genre or intrument played for example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8735136/61795 have a look at the `array_chunk_vertical()` function in this answer to create the array structure, then use two foreach loops, outer loop for the columns, inner loop for the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this be of any help ? [PHP doc modulo]: http://php.net/manual/fr/language.operators.arithmetic.php EDIT: after reading your last comment/edit, it seems that you can use % operator : your HTML gives < div class="container contclass" >< div class="card-box" >YOUR DATA< /div >< /div >, so count the results of your query, and if %2 then insert a line breaker/clearing in CSS

Comment: Is it possible to do modulo 2 on $cards, then display first half in the first column like shown http://6vdp2s.axshare.com/#g=1&p=search__v2 and then second column displaying other half? I didn't downvote it. I would also like to know why the downvote.

Comment: As far as I understand what you want now, it seems that you need to do is, say, for 21 results, have first 11 on 1st column, last 10 on 2nd column. If so, count results of your query, and use CSS to split the display

Comment: so I can use the num_rows function to see how many results I have, then maybe I could just float them and use ul class with li ?

Comment: also, could you give me a hint on how to use the sorting?

Comment: As you have divs in your html, I would float them, but it's up to you :)

Comment: I tried it using float but it doesn't seem to be working the way I expected. http://playground.eca.ed.ac.uk/~s1670810/leverage_edinburgh/public/search.php  I'm thinking of some sort of clear:both solution possibly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139376/discussion-between-user3801953-and-grs).